# I have an input stream and need to make it look like a file on disk. Possible in Java?

Tags: java, io

I have a third party class that only accepts files but all I can provide is InputStream. Is it possible to make a stream "look" like a file so that I could pass it to the before mentioned class.

Specifically I need to pass this stream to javafx.scene.media.Media() constructor which accepts only a file path. I do not have the file "video.mp4" - only a stream.

```
 // create media player
 Media media = new Media("video.mp4");
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

Comment: I believe you will have to create a file, [see here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-file-in-java/).

Comment: What do you mean by *looks like a file*? Can you produce a temporary file and use it in your 3rd part library?

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: I have a stream that comes from encrypted source and can't be decrypted to actual file. I also have a class that actually needs a file location.

Comment: Can you make your question more cryptic please?

Comment: On what operating system are you running your code? You could use named pipes for this, but how to work with them and their semantics are OS-dependent

Comment: You can create an in memory virtual drive and a file in it. This way you avoid disk IO.

Comment: I have edited the question adding specifics. Maybe this would help. Thank you all so much for your comments by the way.

Comment: Suitable dupe, but no real way to work with the issue: [Playing mp3 files in JavaFx from input stream](//stackoverflow.com/q/13539814)

Comment: The `Media` support `https` and `http`,how your inputstream come from ?

Comment: It comes from encrypted file.